# How do I upgrade to from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, 18.10

How do I upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 18.10? I'm new to Ubuntu and would like to know how. Thanks.

Comment: It is bad idea. Consider to install 18.10 on VM for testing. By installing non-LTS version you will lose 5 years support cycle and will obtain new headache.

Answer (score 0):

Open ›Software and Update‹ and select there to notify you for ›any new version‹.
When closing it will ask you if you want to reload your sources, click ›reload‹.
[Software and Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfMcw.png)

The open a terminal an run `sudo do-release-upgrade` and follow the instructions. If you don't want to use a terminal, just wait and you will be ask, if you wish to upgrade.